# Getting parent branch in JGit

Tags: jgit

I'm working on a project where I create a bare repository from a remote one, and fetch only one branch. What I'm trying to find out now is the name of the parent branch (or more specifically, the commit on the parent branch where this branch was created from) to identify the commits that were done on this branch only. For example, if my repository has a `RefSpec` for branch `featureA` only, and this was created from branch `development` on remote from commit `123`, what can I do to find out this info?